What is DRAM cache on SSDs actually used for?
I've found a very interesting article that provides an in-depth explanation about how do SSDs work:
https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/06/inside-the-ssd-revolution-how-solid-state-disks-really-work/
But it says that DRAM cache is actually used as write cache. That's why I initially avoided it, and only looked for DRAM-less SSDs: it's very much possible that the controller won't have enough time to flush 1-2 GB of small files while it still has the charge. So IMHO it definitely should NOT answer back to the OS that the data is "on the platters" (or "in the chips" in our case).
But then I've learned that this is in fact not what DRAM cache is used for; I've found multiple instances saying that it's just used to read-cache the FTL allocation tables so that a suitable place could be found more quickly.
I wonder which one is correct?
I'm pretty sure that pseudo-SLC cache is used for write caching, since many SSD reviews have to account for this; write speed usually goes way down after the first (usually) 2 GB written (at once). That seems better already... as long as it's properly picked up after a power loss. But what if it is not? I can very well imagine how the cache area could be treated as "empty" after a controller restart.
So, are there SSDs for both DRAM cache for the FTL allocation table and pseudo-SLC write-cache? Or is DRAM cache really used as write-cache?

1-2 GB I don't think you'd get that much of DRAM cache anyway. and only looked for DRAM-less SSDs usually they would use the system memory (of the size of 16~32MiB, I think) as their cache ("Host Memory Buffer"; not the same thing as "dirty pages", which could be of a much larger total size, AFAIK).

In my experience, even average-to-cheap DRAM-less NVMe SSDs (like WD Blue) are not as slow as you (seemed to have) thought, even when HMB cannot be leveraged (e.g., when they are in UAS enclosures). Besides, it's really unlikely the OS would wait until there are 1-2 GB of small files before it flushes, and I'm pretty sure volatile write cache on the drive / HMB are essentially "OS-managed", in the sense that when a "sync" occur, it will make sure it sync "down to the bottom" (by triggering protocol-specific sync command).
